# Plural word make an otherwise matching questions score badly in search ranking

Tags: feature-request, search, plurals

If I search for `+hashtable +float`, the questions [Is it safe to use floats as keys of hashtables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399225/is-it-safe-to-use-floats-as-keys-of-hashtables) ranks 35 out of 60 question, merely because it has plural for hashtable and float in the title.

Also, unless I'm mistaken, it do not rate amongst the first 1500 result if I'm searching for `float hashtable`. (No plus sign)

Do you hate plural word that much, Stack Exchanges?

Perhaps I should use tag rather than plain texts, but there are several tag associated with floating point, such as [float](/questions/tagged/float), [floating](/questions/tagged/floating), [floating-accuracy](/questions/tagged/floating-accuracy), [floating-point-precision](/questions/tagged/floating-point-precision), and sometimes [hash](/questions/tagged/hash) is used when [hashtable](/questions/tagged/hashtable) ought to be used.

**tl;dr**: Improving of search ordering would be appreciated if it's practical.

Comment: More technically, it's ranked lower because there's only matches for your terms in the post body, since the words in the title aren't considered matches at all. Plural stemming is tricky, and I don't think Lucene supports it out-of-the-box, so I don't suspect we'll see this changed any time soon (although it certainly would be helpful).

Comment: Did you intentionally mix up most of the subject-verb agreement in this post?

Comment: @JasonPlank: Have you read the [meta-tag:plurals] tag wiki?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I has now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow search is good for searching patterns such as `user:xxx [tag] is:answer votes:xxx`. Don't rely on Stack Overflow search if you *really* want to search for a particular question (or best matches). Use Google instead. Searching for

```
site:stackoverflow.com hashtable float
```

I get pretty good results. Your example is third in the list.

[image]

Comment: -1 "Just Google it" is not an answer... Oops, wrong site, nevermind.